# distinct + rank over join

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

lets say we have a table BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST with these columns:

```
Column Name                          ID   Pk    Null? Data Type
BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_ID1                  1          N     NUMBER (15)
BNK_ACCT_ID                          2          N     NUMBER (15)
BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID                      3          N     NUMBER (15)
BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_CD                   4          N     NUMBER (4)
BNK_ACGRP_ST_SRC_EVNT_TYP_CD         8          N     NUMBER (4)
BNK_ACGRP_ST_SRC_TRAN_ID             9          N     NUMBER (15)
FNCL_GRP_ID                          10         N     NUMBER (15)
CREN_DT                              12         N     DATE
LAST_UPD_DT                          13         N     DATE
PCSG_DT                              14         N     DATE
BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_SEQ_NO               15         N     NUMBER (15)
```

its populated with bnk_accts data :

example#1:

```
BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_ID  BNK_ACCT_ID BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_CD BNK_ACGRP_ST_SRC_EVNT_TYP_CD FNCL_GRP_ID BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_SEQ_NO
2282                150627009   1724            4                  150                          111111111   2
2283                150627009   1440            2                  149                          111111112   1
1908                150627009   1725            2                  134                          111111111   1
1906                150627009   1441            2                  135                          111111111   7
```

and example #2:

```
BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_ID  BNK_ACCT_ID BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_CD BNK_ACGRP_ST_SRC_EVNT_TYP_CD FNCL_GRP_ID BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_SEQ_NO
2364                150275031   1435            2                  114                          133333333   3
2365                150275031   1436            7                  116                          133333333   2
1902                150275031   1435            1                  72                           133333333   2
1903                150275031   1435            2                  36                           133333333   1
1904                150275031   1436            5                  74                           133333333   1
```

where:

- BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_ID is autoincrement field,
- BNK_ACCT_ID is actualy bank account # id,
- BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID is grp id (which always increasing),
- BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST_CD, BNK_ACGRP_ST_SRC_EVNT_TYP_CD and BNK_ACGRP_ST_SRC_TRAN_ID are some id's for trans purposes,
- FNCL_GRP_ID - id of the bankiing insitution where this bank acc belongs to

what i need : to create a query to pull latest BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID for each BNK_ACCT_ID based on FNCL_GRP_ID. here one bank acc can belongs to one or more then one fncl instituion, so the query should return this output:

for example#1:

```
FNCL_GRP_ID  BNK_ACCT_ID  BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID
111111111    150627009    1725
111111112    150627009    1440
```

for example#2:

```
FNCL_GRP_ID  BNK_ACCT_ID  BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID
133333333    150275031    1436
```

I have tried a lot of the things lately, such as a combo of

```
(select distinct BNK_ACCT_ID,FNCL_GRP_ID) join to rank() over (partiton  by )
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH BankData AS
(
    SELECT  a.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER()
              OVER(PARTITION BY fncl_grp_id, bnk_acct_id ORDER BY bnk_acct_grp_id DESC) AS Position
      FROM bnk_acct_grp_st a
)
SELECT  *
  FROM  BankData
 WHERE  Position = 1
```

Comment: Chandu, thanks, i just did not figure out that its easy to use more then 1 partition here

Answer (score 0):

[@Chandu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11316880/297408) is a rather universal solution allowing you to pull arbitrary columns along with the maximum values. But if you only need those three columns (`FNCL_GRP_ID`, `BNK_ACCT_ID`, `BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID`) in the output, you could also use a good old `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
  FNCL_GRP_ID,
  BNK_ACCT_ID,
  MAX(BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID) AS BNK_ACCT_GRP_ID
FROM BNK_ACCT_GRP_ST
GROUP BY
  FNCL_GRP_ID,
  BNK_ACCT_ID
```